# 2 foreign key num só campo

Tags: mysql

Boas,

Eu tenho 3 tabelas:

- Atleta

  - Id (Pk)
  - Nome
- AtletaF

  - Id (PK)
  - Nome
  - NFed
- Acompanhantes

  - Id (PK)
  - Nome
  - Tipo
  - Atleta (FK)

O campo **Atleta** na tabela **Acompanhantes** é o **Id** da tabela **Atleta** e da tabela **AtletaF**.

Como eu faço em **mySQL** para que junte as tabelas?

Alguém sabe?

Comment: Qual a diferença entre as tabelas Atleta e AtletaF?

Comment: peço desculpa falta um campo vou editar agora

Comment: Quais as tabelas que queres juntar? Qual o resultado que pretendes obter?

Comment: @bruno eu quero juntar os id das tabelas atleta e atletaf à tabela acompanhantes, para mostrar, mais logo, o nome dos acompanhantes e o nome do atleta que vão acompanhar.

Comment: @bruno é de referir que os Id's são auto_increment todos.

Comment: Você não consegue criar uma *foreign key* que faça referência a duas tabelas.

Comment: Sim, mas qual a relação entre as duas tabelas Atleta e AtletaF? Como determinas na tabela se a pessoa está a acompanhar um atleta da tabela Atletas ou da tabela AtletaF? Porque não juntar as duas tabelas numa só?

Comment: @ Eu tenho duas paginas **HTML** com **form** para as duas. Se se inscrever no **form** para atleta normal, o **tipo** da tabela **Acompanhante** fica 0. Se se inscrever no **form** para atleta federado o **tipo** fica 1.

Comment: Então para que serve a tabela `Atleta` @BrunoGibellino?

Comment: Faça uma tabela só , ATLETA , o NUMERO_FEDERACAO indica se é "federado".

Comment: @Motta o problema é que preciso que o id comece no 1 para o federado e o não federado

Comment: Para que @BrunoGibellino?

Comment: @JorgeB. Porque se for federado vai para uma pista se não for federado vai para outra

Comment: e que tem isso a ver com o id?

Comment: Basta teres uma tabela, a `Atletaf`, e verificares se é ou não federado `if(NFed==0)//não é federado`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu *design* está errado. Todo atleta federado é um atleta; você quer fazer *herança relacional*. O seu design tem que ser algo tipo

```
CREATE TABLE Atleta (
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE AtletaF (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NFed TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Atleta (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE Acompanhantes (
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    Tipo TEXT NOT NULL,
    Atleta INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Atleta) REFERENCES Atleta (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Tendo dito isso, esse design tem outros problemas também:

- Um atleta pode estar associado a mais de uma federação ao longo da sua vida? Se sim, a sua tabela `AtletaF` precisa ter uma referência a uma nova tabela, `Federacao`, e, se ele puder estar associado a mais de uma federação ao mesmo tempo, `AtletaF` tem que ter uma chave primária composta.
- Não sei qual é o seu conceito de acompanhante, mas um acompanhante pode acompanhar mais de um atleta? Se sim, você precisa quebrar essa chave estrangeira pra fazer uma relação muitos-muitos, com uma tabela auxiliar, digamos, `AcompanhanteAtleta`, e mover a FK `Atleta` pra lá.
- *Last but not least*, uma tabela se chama `Atleta` e a outra `Acompanhantes`. Eu sou partidário de nomear tabelas no singular, mas eu entendo que há controvérias — se você quiser nomear tudo no plural OK, mas seja consistente.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível criar uma chave estrangeira que aponte para duas tabelas diferentes.

O que você pode fazer é desnormalizar, ou seja juntar, as tabelas `Atleta` e `AtletaF` e criar algum critério nesta nova tabela para definir se o atleta é federado ou não. Acredito eu que o campo `NFED` pode fazer este trabalho.

Outra opção seria a tabela `Acompanhantes` ter duas chaves estrangeiras: Uma para `Atleta` e outra para `AtletaF`.